# How to skip last row in datatable export option (.csv pdf options)

Tags: jquery, excel, datatable, datatables, pdf-generation

My script is below.
I want to skip my last row in excel and pdf.

```
$('.data-grid-export').DataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            footer: true,
        },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            footer: false
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a class or Id to the last row using, for example, initComplete:

```
initComplete : function(){
    $(".data-grid-export tr").last().addClass("notPrintable");
}
```

and then use the [exportOptions](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html) option of `buttons` to specify all rows except the one with the class/id:

```
buttons:[
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            exportOptions:{
                rows: ':not(.notPrintable)'
            }
        }
```

This worked in my table, hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

User customize Option
A Simple Sample for Export Excel was shown as below:

```
customize: function (xlsx) {
                                    var sheet =xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                                    $('row', sheet).filter(function () {
                                        var attr = $(this).attr('r');
                                        if (attr == $('row', sheet).length) //last row
                                            return true;
                                        return false;
                                    }).remove();
                           }
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTables [row-selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) support jQuery selectors, so the easiest way to skip last row is :

```
{
  extend: 'pdfHtml5',
  exportOptions: {
    rows: ':not(:last)'
  }
}
```